# Why does Windows Azure Western Europe have U.S IP Address?

Tags: networking, azure

Like the question says, I'm really having a problem where, although I've signed up for a Western Europe Windows Azure VM, whenever I access a site or service from this server I'm getting assigned a U.S IP Address.

This is really problematic because those services require my IP to be in Europe. Anyone else have this issue and know how I can change the IP somehow?

Thanks

Comment: The address is determined by the gateway you connect by.  Have you asked microsoft for a different gateway?

Answer (score 0):

There's no country-specific affinity with IP addresses. Microsoft chooses the IP address ranges for its data centers. You can see a recent list (July 2013) [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2013/08/14/windows-azure-datacenter-ip-ranges.aspx).

There's no way to choose your external IP address; this is assigned to you when you deploy your service (Virtual Machines or Cloud Services with web/worker roles). For Web Sites, the external IP address is shared, given that Web Sites is a multi-tenant system. With Virtual Machines & Cloud Services, you'll get a unique IP address assigned on a per-deployment basis (yourname.cloudapp.net gets an IP).